# How Do I Add a Reference to SqlServerSpatial.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have a desktop application deployed to my web server that's throwing an error saying it can't find SqlServerSpatial.dll.  If I add that manually to my deployment package, it works just fine.  But, I don't want to do it this way... I want to automatically include the dll when I build the project.  Problem is, when I try to add the reference in Visual Studio, it says:

> A reference to '[Path]\SqlServerSpatial.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just adding it to the root to your project as an existing file and setting it to "Copy to output directory"

Comment: Yeah, and that actually works.  But, I don't wanna rely on myself to remember to manually add the DLL every time the project needs to be updated.

Comment: As far as i know its your only option, You shouldn't need to add the dll to the project everytime its updated it should remain in the source directory and push it out when you publish it.

Comment: Source Directory?  The project in question is a Web Job that goes up on Azure.  The way it works is, you build the project, zip up all the output files and upload the .zip file.  So, once I build it, I have to manually copy over the SqlServerSpatial dll's and put them into the zip file.  Isn't there a way to tell the project to just include them in the output during the build?

Comment: If your using Visual Studio, Right click on your project and select Add>Existing File this should add the dll to your project as a source file. Click the file in solution explorer and make sure "Copy to Output Directory" is "Copy Always" Now when you build the project it should be there.